# how to set inline style in react jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to apply the inline styles in react component as follows. Is this the right way to set styles, if not how can i achieve this?

```
  <div
    {...customProps}
    style={{ width: `${widthValue}%`,
      animationDelay: `${animationDelay}s`,
      zIndex: `${zIndex}`,
      animation: `loadbar ${incrementValue}s linear forwards`}}
    key={i}
    className={`well-background--${group.concept}
      well-GroupedProgressBar--progress
      well-GroupedProgressBar--${props.heightSize}`}
  />,
```

Thanks

Comment: How have you tried to test this?

Comment: I believe this is the correct approach. As other answer suggest, you can use custom variable for it, however your solution should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the obj to inline styles attribute. Your code is correct, however you can clean up your code by preparing the style object in  the render function if its changing everytime like

```
render() {
    var style = {
      width: `${widthValue}%`,
      animationDelay: `${animationDelay}s`,
      zIndex: `${zIndex}`,
      animation: `loadbar ${incrementValue}s linear forwards`
    }
    return (
        <div
           {...customProps}
           style={style}
           key={i}
           className={`well-background--${group.concept}
                        well-GroupedProgressBar--progress
                       well-GroupedProgressBar--${props.heightSize}`
                      }
          />

    )
}
```

Comment: You did basically same thing as he did, only thing that is different is that you used variable for it ;)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, I did try that but i dont see any difference. the thing is `animation: `loadbar ${incrementValue}s linear forwards`` property is not getting applied so i thought if i am doing something wrong